# Problems styling UL with table-cell

Tags: html, css

I want to show my the section "How it works" of my website like this:

https://codepen.io/carlosmr/pen/NVbbmx

The problem is that if the text is too long at the right the numbers at the left grow with it, like in number 4.

Is there a way to leave the numbers at the left and the text at the right without that problem? Thanks!

```css
.uli {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.uli li {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.uli li span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 3em;
}

.uli li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 49px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    z-index: -1;
}

.uli li:last-child:before {
    display: none;
}
.uli .ulcontent{
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 padding-left: 100px;
}
.entry-content .uli > li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="uli">
    <li>
     <span>1</span>
     <div class="ulcontent">
      <h3>Primer contacto</h3>
      <p>Contactas conmigo y me cuentas tu idea. Si quieres puedes hacerlo <a href="#">Aquí</a></p>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span>2</span>
     <div class="ulcontent">
      <h3>Consultoría web</h3>
      <p>Organizamos una entrevista para conocernos y aclarar las bases del proyecto.</p>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span>3</span>
     <div class="ulcontent">
      <h3>Diseño web</h3>
      <p>Empieza la creación de un diseño para tu proyectos basado en las necesidades del mismo</p>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span>4</span>
     <div class="ulcontent">
      <h3>Desarrollo</h3>
      <p>Una vez se apruebe el diseño definitivo comenzamos la fase de desarrollo, en la cual se programa el tema totalmente desde cero y se le añaden todas las funcionalidades a la web</p>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span>5</span>
     <div class="ulcontent">
      <h3>Implementación</h3>
      <p>En este momento se añade el contenido, se personaliza y se traslada a tu servidor para que puedas administrarlo tu mismo</p>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span>6</span>
     <div class="ulcontent">
      <h3>Consultoría previa</h3>
      <p>Nos reuniremos por videoconferencia para conocernos y sentar las bases de lo que será tu nuevo sitio de membresía. ¿Estás listo? ¡Vamos allá!</p>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the below styles to the `<span>` tag which is inside the `<li>` tag.

```
display: block;
float: left;
line-height: 100px;
```

Check the edited codepen

[Edited version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RmoKob)